# Consider using Ajax Fancy Captcha instead of Recaptcha

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, captcha, ajax

I saw this in use on someones blog today:
http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin

I've had a long standing hatred of Captcha's, even though they are a necessary evil. It frustrates me when I have to squint to try and read the text, or when I stuff it up 2 or 3 times. It's a barrier to user contribution, but unfortunately due to the nature of the internet we need to use it.

I quite liked the look of this fancy captcha plugin though - simple, stuff you would do as a child, yet should be fine to block the bots. It's a jquery plugin too, I believe that stack overflow uses that.

If this plugin isn't quite right, perhaps a similar concept could be developed by stack overflow?

Comment: This just reminds me of [Kitten Captcha](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/kitten-captcha/). Could _easily_ be converted into Waffle Captcha, Unicorn-Captcha or [your-favorite-meme-here]-Captcha.

Comment: On an **almost completely** unrelated note, what is with websites that use Flash to display section headers - in this website's case, just plain text?

Comment: @Jared - That would be [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr): a method for getting non web-safe fonts for your website before `@font-face` became widely supported.

Comment: @Yij Interesting - thanks! I only noticed since I started running Chrome in "click to play" for plugins

Answer (score 11):

One key difference is that we allow posting with JavaScript disabled, and ReCaptcha supports this.

So that's a dealbreaker.

On top of that, I'm not a fan of these drag and drop captchas as they also break users who navigate with the keyboard or are blind.

Not really an option.

Comment: And the reason they aren't cracked yet is that nobody serious uses them. There's really nothing going on there that wouldn't be trivially solvable.

Comment: Not only breaking it for keyboard users, but I just tried their example on my iPhone, and you can't use the captcha on a touchscreen interface - seeing as how big mobile computing is, well, I think that's a dealbreaker too.

Comment: I would wager that 150 rep would get that particular captcha solved with a drop-in solution in less than half a day. If not that, 500 would certainly do it.